# Alternative to using macros for changing old code

Tags: c++, macros, raii

I'm trying to re-factor some old code with [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) pattern. The old code manages resource allocation, but expects users to lock/unlock the resource explicitly. So for example, something like this (just an example, not real code):

```
void modify(int id){
    lock();
    modify_data_related_to_id(id);
    unlock();
}
```

will become something like this:

```
void modify(int id){
    RAIIOBJ obj;
    modify_data_related_to_id(id);
}
```

The benefit being that you don't have to remember to `unlock` the object. When the `RAIIOBJ` gets deleted, unlock will be called automatically in its destructor.

The problem is, there're a ton of places that has to be re-factored. I was thinking I'll use macros and replace the `lock` call with the RAII call and `unlock` will become a no-op function like:

```
#define lock() RAIIOBJ obj;
void unlock(){ //empty function
}
```

This way I don't have to change every place the lock/unlock is called to use the RAII method. However, is there some better way - maybe there's a pattern just for sort of problem - to do this, than using a macro.

Comment: Can you modify `RAIIOBJ`?

Comment: Clang offers deep, AST-based, codebase-wide refactoring tools. Just because you have many such call sites doesn't mean that you have a lot of work to do.

Comment: @Columbo. Yes I can modify RAIIOBJ.
Kerrek SB : Thanks for CLang reference. Will check it out.

Comment: @ArunR If the above macros will do the trick, couldnt you just do search and replace in your entire codebase for this string? Expand these macros manually :) And by manually, I mean use find and sed.

Comment: @Pradhan I guess I can do what you suggested. I just need to replace the `lock` part of the code. Will give it a try if nothing else comes up. Thanks

Comment: Your macro based solution can cause compilation errors, which is not so bad, but also deadlocks, which is worse (for example `lock(); if(x) { unlock(); lock(); } unlock();` or `lock(); unlock(); f();` where function `f` can also lock). I also fail to see benefit - people still see `lock/unlock`, but now it has different semantics. Be careful with automated solutions.

Comment: @zch Thanks for pointing out the deadlock issue. I gave a lock/unlock example since it is a common practice to use RAII. My code actually uses this method for memory allocation on a stack model, which will take longer to explain. But suffices to say this code can handle `"recursive locks"`.

Comment: @ArunR, recursive locks can also get deadlocked, as you are extending code area that is locked. You can ensure the scope in most cases with something like `class ScopeProtect{ int scope_protect_member; };` `#define lock() { ScopeProtect obj; { RAIIOBJ obj;` `#define unlock() } (void)obj.scope_protect_member; }`. But I wouldn't do it, I would either leave the old api as it is (possibly deprecated) or make changes manually.